# Postfix, Dovecot - connection from outside, authentication

Tags: centos, postfix, authentication, dovecot

I want to run postfix + dovecot on my server. I'm doing it for first time. Postfix and Dovecot works on local - I can connect through telnet, and send/receive e-mails using commands.
When I try to connect from outside, using mail client (in my case Thunderbird), I always see in client alert: `Authentication failed`.

My */var/log/maillog* file says:

`dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Shutting down (auth failed, 6 attempts): user=<test.user>, method=PLAIN, rip=xxx.xxx.xxx, lip=xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Distribution is CentOS 6

EDIT (`postconf -n`):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = host.mydomain.com
mynetworks = xxx.xxx.xxx/24 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

When I want to send an e-mail to outside host from Thunderbird, I get `5.7.1 <my_address@gmail.com>: Relay access denied`.

Error log for this:
`NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from my_vps_domain[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <myaddress@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<test.user@mydomain.com> to=<myaddress@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>`

Answer (score 2):

You should post the contents of your 10-auth.conf and all the auth* snippet config files. There's any number of things that can be going wrong. You can start troubleshooting here:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/TestPop3Installation

and you can turn on debug logging with the "auth_debug" and "auth_verbose" directives.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Debugging/Authentication

Comment: Thank you. Dovecot problem solved, but still I have problem with sending emails from mail client. Can you look at postconf in 1st post?

Answer (score 2):

Here the explanation for second part of your problem:

Here, postfix rejected attempt to send email via mail client with error "Relay access denied". It means thunderbird doesn't attempt to do SMTP AUTH so it doesn't permitted with configuration `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Based on the output of `postconf -n`, you seems haven't enable SASL authentication in postfix. That's why Thunderbird doesn't authenticated himself thus caused email rejected.

You can find the tutorial about enabling SASL in [postfix official docs](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html).